# Laravel: How to get SUM of a relation column using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

**How to get SUM on related model using eager loading, without loading whole relation data?**

In my project there are two models, `Account` and `Transaction`. Account model `has many` transactions.

**My requirement is** : ***Get accounts and eager load only the sum on the related table***.

**My current code is provided** : In this code `transactions` are eager loaded and sum is calculated using php. But I would prefer not to load the whole transactions. The only requirement is `sum('amount')`.

table : ***accounts***

```
| id | name | address | ...
```

table : ***transactions***

```
| id | account_id | amount | ...
```

**Account.php**

```
/**
 * Get the transaction records associated with the account.
 */
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction', 'account_id');
}
```

The following code gives each accounts and its transactions.

```
$account = Account::with(['transactions'])->get();
```

SUM is calculated using :

```
foreach ($accounts as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->transactions->sum('amount'). " <br />";
}
```

I have tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction', 'account_id')->sum('amount;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need sub query to do that. I'll show you some solution:

- Solution 1

  ```php
  $amountSum = Transaction::selectRaw('sum(amount)')
      ->whereColumn('account_id', 'accounts.id')
      ->getQuery();

  $accounts = Account::select('accounts.*')
      ->selectSub($amountSum, 'amount_sum')
      ->get();

  foreach($accounts as $account) {
      echo $account->amount_sum;
  }
  ```
- Solution 2

  Create a `withSum` macro to the EloquentBuilder.

  ```php
  use Illuminate\Support\Str;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
  use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;

  Builder::macro('withSum', function ($columns) {
      if (empty($columns)) {
          return $this;
      }

      if (is_null($this->query->columns)) {
          $this->query->select([$this->query->from.'.*']);
      }

      $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();
      $columnAndConstraints = [];

      foreach ($columns as $name => $constraints) {
          // If the "name" value is a numeric key, we can assume that no
          // constraints have been specified. We'll just put an empty
          // Closure there, so that we can treat them all the same.
          if (is_numeric($name)) {
              $name = $constraints;
              $constraints = static function () {
                  //
              };
          }

          $columnAndConstraints[$name] = $constraints;
      }

      foreach ($columnAndConstraints as $name => $constraints) {
          $segments = explode(' ', $name);

          unset($alias);

          if (count($segments) === 3 && Str::lower($segments[1]) === 'as') {
              [$name, $alias] = [$segments[0], $segments[2]];
          }

          // Here we'll extract the relation name and the actual column name that's need to sum.
          $segments = explode('.', $name);

          $relationName = $segments[0];
          $column = $segments[1];

          $relation = $this->getRelationWithoutConstraints($relationName);

          $query = $relation->getRelationExistenceQuery(
              $relation->getRelated()->newQuery(),
              $this,
              new Expression("sum(`$column`)")
          )->setBindings([], 'select');

          $query->callScope($constraints);

          $query = $query->mergeConstraintsFrom($relation->getQuery())->toBase();

          if (count($query->columns) > 1) {
              $query->columns = [$query->columns[0]];
          }

          // Finally we will add the proper result column alias to the query and run the subselect
          // statement against the query builder. Then we will return the builder instance back
          // to the developer for further constraint chaining that needs to take place on it.
          $column = $alias ?? Str::snake(Str::replaceFirst('.', ' ', $name.'_sum'));

          $this->selectSub($query, $column);
      }

      return $this;
  });
  ```

  Then, you can use it just like when you're using `withCount`, except you need to add column that need to sum after the relationships (`relation.column`).

  ```php
  $accounts = Account::withSum('transactions.amount')->get();

  foreach($accounts as $account) {
      // You can access the sum result using format `relation_column_sum`
      echo $account->transactions_amount_sum;
  }
  ```

  ```php
  $accounts = Account::withSum(['transactions.amount' => function (Builder $query) {
      $query->where('status', 'APPROVED');
  })->get();
  ```

Comment: Nice. Please kindly accept the answer if it's answering your question 

Comment: `$records->withCount("invoiceItem");` 
       `$records->withSum("invoiceItem", 'quantity');`
       `$records->withSum("fk_item_id", 'selling_price_to');`

Answer (score 1):

If `Account hasMany Transactions`, you could use the following query to get the amount

```
Account::with(['transactions' =>  function( $q) {
    $q->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum_amount, account_id')->groupBy('account_id');
}
```

You need to make sure that `account_id` is selected in the Closure otherwise the relationship would not work.

Alternatively, you could also define another relationship like `transactionSums` as below in Account Model:

```
public function transactionSums() {

    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class)->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum_amount, account_id')->groupBy('account_id');
}
```

Then your controller code will be cleaner as below:

```
$accounts = Account::with(['transactionSums' ]);

foreach($accounts as $account)
{
    echo $account->transactionSums[0]->sum_amount;
}
```

Comment: @nmfzone I am not sure what you are referring to as mess. I have shown 2 ways to achieve the result and code is straightforward.

Comment: @ascsoftw Thank you for the answer. I have tested both solutions. Both works. Please note, you have a typo in `sum(account)`, it should be `sum(amount)`. To get the result `$account->transactionSum[0]->sumAmount`

Comment: @ab_ Glad to help. Sorry about the typo, I misread the column name.

Comment: @ascsoftw You're showing how to solve, but not showing how to get the result. Show us how to get the sum of amount on each iteration..

Comment: @nmfzone The sum is present in the object. Its not a big deal to fetch the value from object. The real issue was getting the sum using eager loading.

Comment: @ascsoftw You're right about that. Then, I was right about it's too mess to get the result on each iteration. Of course it's matter, that's a big deal..

Comment: @nmfzone `$account->transactionSums[0]->sum;` on each iteration does not seems messy to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Whoops, I completely replaced `SUM` with `COUNT` in my head.** While this will not directly solve your issue, the underlying code for `whereCount()` may provide some insight.

---

[Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

```php
$accounts = Account::withCount('transactions')->get();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $transactionCount = $account->transactions_count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was looking for `withSum()`.  Something like `withCount()`.