# Laravel sum nested relationship column

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I tried sum nested related column but get empty result.

**Code:**

```
$data = CropType::with(['categories' => function($cq) {
    return $cq->with(['varieties' => function($vq) {
        return $vq->with(['products' => function($pq) {
            return $pq->sum('total');
        }]);
    }]);
}])->get();
```

As you can see, I have 4 tables that are interconnected with foreign keys

- Table: **crop_types**

  `id`

  `title`
- Table: **categories**

  `id`

  `title`

  `crop_type_id`
- Table: **varieties**

  `id`

  `title`

  `category_id`
- Table: **products**

  `id`

  `title`

  `total`

  `variety_id`

But when I run my query it's run as like this instead summing total products:

`"select * from crop_types"`

How I can correctly sum total products in each crop type?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58668526/6274211)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query to get total products in each crop type:

**SQL**

```
SELECT crop_types.id,
         crop_types.title AS title,
         sum(products.total) AS total
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `varieties`
    ON `varieties`.`id` = `products`.`variety_id`
INNER JOIN `categories`
    ON `categories`.`id` = `varieties`.`category_id`
INNER JOIN `crop_types`
    ON `crop_types`.`id` = `categories`.`crop_type_id`
GROUP BY  `crop_types`.`id`
```

**Laravel Eloquent**

```
$result = Product::query()
    ->selectRaw('crop_types.id, crop_types.title as title, sum(products.total) as total')
    ->join(
        'varieties',
        'varieties.id',
        '=',
        'products.variety_id'
    )
    ->join(
        'categories',
        'categories.id',
        '=',
        'varieties.category_id'
    )
    ->join(
        'crop_types',
        'crop_types.id',
        '=',
        'categories.crop_type_id'
    )
    ->groupBy('crop_types.id')
    ->get();
```